# How to choose what line to print from a txt file in python

Tags: python

I want to print a specific line from a txt file like from a txt file like this:

"line number 1"

"line number 2"

"line number 3"

I want to print line number 3 and 2 how do I do that?

Comment: Do you always want to print line 2 and 3, or beacuse of some condition they meet? Or do you just need to skip the first?

Comment: i want to get a number from the user and print the number of lune he choose from the end like if he choose 1 i print only the last line, 2 the two last lines

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to print from `start_line` to `end_line`. You can do as follows:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    rows = f.readlines()[start_line - 1 : end_line]
    print(rows)
```

If `start_line` is `2` and `end_line` is `3`, it will print 2nd and 3rd lines of `test.txt`

Comment: Please change your answer per user comment section "choose 1 i print only the last line, 2 the two last lines"

Comment: you can play with [1:], for example [0:10] means print from the beginning to 9 rows. [1:] means to start from the second line to infinte.

Comment: Check out this code `list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6]; ind = input('Enter Number : '); print(list_[-int(ind):])`. But user want last n values. I just want that you should change you answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you:

```
from collections import deque

try:
    num = int(input("Number of last lines to print:"))
except:
    num = 1

a_file = open("data.txt")

lines = a_file.readlines()

for line in deque(lines, num):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Done. Updated my answer

Comment: Well change `num` to `int(num)` 

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loading the whole file in memory do not use `readlines`:

```
fname = "data.txt"
skip_num = 2
with open(fname) as f:
    for _ in range(skip_num):
        f.readline()
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Cheers!